# How to pass hidden parameters when redirecting a route ? (With POST ?)

Tags: symfony, post

When I do a redirectToRoute, I want to pass hidden parameters.
Pass the parameter in a route does not satisfating me, because I want the information hidden.
I was thinking to do that with POST, but I don't know how to pass POST parameters in the redirectToRoute function.
Can I do that ?

Comment: No parameters for a redirect.  And the next time you have a browser running, press F12 then click on the network tab.  Then ask yourself how exactly can you hide information from even a slightly knowledgeable user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't redirect a POST request because the browser would have to resend the POST data , so you have to use forward like:

```
return $this->redirectToRoute('name_of_route_to_redirect', ['max' => 10,...]);
```

For more information , take a see in the documentation [symfony controller](https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller.html#forwarding-to-another-controller)

You can send the Request object inside :

```
return $this->redirectToRoute('route', [
    'request' => $request
], 307);
```

> that 307 guarantees that the method and the body will not be changed
>   when the redirected request is made

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is storing your parameters in some file/memory cache.

You redirect without parameters and on your action you check if you have some parameters in the file/memory cache and get them from there.

I don't know if it's a good thing to do though, but it seems possible to do.